# Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client IsSuccessStatusCode not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Environment:
    .net 4.0 console app

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client version=4.0.30506.0 targetFramework="net40" 

Microsoft.Net.Http" version=2.0.20710.0 targetFramework="net40" 

Newtonsoft.Json version=4.5.11 targetFramework="net40"
```

Ok, so I have set up a self hosted web API service, and I am able to access that service without issue. 
I would like to gracefully handle the scenario where the service is not running.

The problem is the code errors out on the GetAsync call, before it can even check IsSuccessStatusCode .

However if I start up Fiddler, then the code runs as I expect, which seems really strange to me.

Here is some demo code.

```
Private Function GetConnInfo(hostIP As String, hostPort As Integer) As Boolean
    GetConnInfo = False
    Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    client.BaseAddress = New Uri("http://" & hostIP & ":" & hostPort)
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))

    Dim resp = client.GetAsync("api/clientconnectioninfo/GetAllConnections").Result

    If resp.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
        GetConnInfo = True
    End If

    Return GetConnInfo

End Function
```

Stack Trace:

```
System.AggregateException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233088
Message=One or more errors occurred.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at DemoApiServiceNotRunning.Module1.GetConnInfo(String hostIP, Int32 hostPort) in C:\Users\tonye\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DemoApiServiceNotRunning\DemoApiServiceNotRunning\Module1.vb:line 19
at DemoApiServiceNotRunning.Module1.Main() in C:\Users\tonye\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DemoApiServiceNotRunning\DemoApiServiceNotRunning\Module1.vb:line 8
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
   HResult=-2146233088
   Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
   InnerException: System.Net.WebException
        HResult=-2146233079
        Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
        Source=System
        StackTrace:
             at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
             at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
             ErrorCode=10061
             HResult=-2147467259
             Message=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.20.124:8700
             NativeErrorCode=10061
             Source=System
             StackTrace:
                  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                  at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
             InnerException:`
```

Comment: What do you mean on " errors out "? Can you post the exception message?

Comment: I was just doing that.

Comment: `IsSuccessStatusCode` is for checking that the response was in the 200-299 range for that you need to have a response. So you cannot use the `IsSuccessStatusCode` when the server is not running you need to catch the `AggregateException` and inspect it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsSuccessStatusCode will only return a value if a HTTP request is made.  If it can't connect to the server you will get an exception throw instead.  It works with fiddler running because your client is actually connecting to fiddler and then fiddler is trying to connect to your server.

You have two choices.  Either catch the Exception, or install a second self-host web api that is running on the same port but using a Weak Wildcard.  That second service will only get hit if your main service is not running.

Comment: So fiddler is actually generating the http response?

Comment: @Wieknot Yup.  It's acting like any proxy would.